# Missing Files In A Sequence

Tags: linux, bash, sequence

I am trying to adapt [this script](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/194539-how-take-missing-sequence-number.html) to work with a directory of .pdf files.  What is different with my file structure is the use of leading 0's.  My files are all 3 digits --- such as

```
001.pdf
002.pdf
...
045.pdf
046.pdf
...
124.pdf
125.pdf
```

Is it possible to make this work?

```
#!/bin/sh
start_number=1
current_number=0
errfound=0
errfiles=""


for file in $(ls); do
    current_number="${start_number}"
    file_error=0
    while read line; do 
        if [ ! "${line}" = "${current_number}" ]; then
            echo "Missing number: ${current_number}"
            file_error=1
        fi  
    done < $file
    if [ "${file_error}" -ne 0 ]; then
        errfiles="${errfiles}${file} "
    fi
done
if [ ! -z "${errfiles}" ]; then
    echo "The following files are missing numbers:"
    echo "${errfiles}"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Bash question that has to do with programming and development, and includes program control flow (and not just how to run a command).

Comment: @jww: Surprising to see a complement from you lol ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the filenames from a file and report any missing names in that list:

```
 awk '{ name = sprintf("%03d.pdf", ++n) }
      { while ($0 != name) {
            printf("Missing file %s\n", name)
            name = sprintf("%03d.pdf", ++n)
        } }' <file
```

Given the file

```
001.pdf
002.pdf
005.pdf
007.pdf
008.pdf
```

This would generate

```
Missing file 003.pdf
Missing file 004.pdf
Missing file 006.pdf
```

---

Assuming you want to find *missing files* in a sequence with `bash`, where each filename should match the pattern `<3 zero-filled digits>.pdf` and where the digits should be between `001` and `125`:

```
for name in {001..125}.pdf
    if [ ! -f "$name" ]; then
        printf 'file "%s" is missing\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
done
```

or with `/bin/sh`:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 125 ]; do
    name=$( printf '%03d.pdf' "$i" )
    if [ ! -f "$name" ]; then
        printf 'file "%s" is missing\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

This iterates with `i` taking the values from 1 to 125.  The expected filename is created using `printf` and the format specification `%03d.pdf`.  The `%03d` is a placeholder for a value that will be converted to "a zero-filled 3-digit decimal integer" (`$i` will be used for this value).

If the expected filename does not exist as a regular file, a message is printed to standard error.

Using `ksh93`:

```
for name in {1..125%03d}.pdf
    if [ ! -f "$name" ]; then
        printf 'file "%s" is missing\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: Apparently it seems OP is reading from a file where these missing gaps are.

Comment: @Inian Ah. I might have been confused by the fact that the elements of the list were all filenames.  I'll add something about that.